# Find out which months have data logged in MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have the date of each customer order stored in the format `02 Mar 2015`

I have data from March and April and I want a query that will return just those 2 months. Once I have data for May it will return the three months etc.

The SQL syntax which I am trying to use is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d %b %y')) FROM orders
```

However this returns 0 rows. I presume this is an issue with date format.

EDIT:

Sample data from table:

id    |    date    |    time   |    order_id    |    item    |    quantity
1   | 02 Mar 2015  | 14:22 | 1029 | clasico | 9
1   | 05 Apr 2015  | 13:58 | 1029 | hindu | 10

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(`order_date`) FROM `orders`
```

where `order_date` is the date field in `orders`

Comment: I've tried that but also 0 rows are returned. I think the problem I have is that I have (stupidly) stored the date in the format "02 Mar 2015" rather than in the format 2015-03-03 02:33:26. Any other ideas?

Comment: date is a mysql function... what is the name of the date field in the table orders, please post the schema and several sample rows... if your date field really IS named date then encalsulate it like `date` using backticks

Comment: it's 'date', perhaps that is causing a conflict?

Comment: post your schema and some sample data

Comment: Edited main post, apologies about the poor formatting!

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The answer assumes the date column is a varchar rather than a datetime datatype.

The *DATE_FORMAT()* function is used to display date/time data in different formats.  Note: This assumes the data is a datetime data type.

The *STR_TO_DATE()* returns a datetime value by taking a string and a specific format string as arguments.  See the code below in action in the [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49b7/6/0).

```
select DISTINCT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d %b %y')) from orders
```